# How to run Viro React Native App with Expo. Using Linux and Iphone

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, augmented-reality

I want to run A react-Native app and use Viro react as a library/plugin  for my AR Application. I am on ubuntu and I have Iphone.
I came to know I can run react-native app via expo go on my iphone but adding Viro React requires to build again with
`expo run:ios` which is not possible because I am on Linux.
Is there any way to do run my react-native AR app on iphone while developing on Linux

```
expo run:ios
iOS apps can only be built on macOS devices. Use eas build -p ios to build in the cloud.
~/D/p/AwesomeProject (master)> eas build -p ios
Command 'eas' not found, did you mean:
```

Answer (score 0):

The only official way to deploy any app to iOS (iPhone) is via Mac operating system.

I don't know of any "inofficial" ways to do this

Comment: I don't want to deploy it on IOS ryt now. I just want to test and develop right now